# Function that is 1 if x is smaller than or equal to 10 and 0 otherwise

Tags: functions

Is there any function that returns 1 if x is smaller than 10 or equal to 10?
Otherwise 0 should be returned.

I need this value as a coefficient for another function. Something should be added or subtracted only if x is smaller than 11.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: see `PieceWise[]`

Comment: `Piecewise` is probably the most intuitive way to go. There's also `UnitStep[10 - x]`.

Comment: My question is about how this is possible without code. Just a mathematical function.

Comment: Are you sure you're in the right Q&A site? Is this really a question about Wolfram Mathematica?

Comment: If your question is not about code, then it's not relevant to Mathematica.SE.  You need to specify what you consider to be a "mathematical function" if you do not consider `Piecewise[]` to be an adequate solution.

Comment: Looks like I am in the completely wrong section. By using the term "mathematical function" I mean something like this: y=sin(2x)*(x/3)

Comment: there is the Heaviside function, which in mathematica is called `UnitStep[]`.

Comment: before someone calls me on this..for the mathematicians there is `HeavisideTheta` which differs from `UnitStep` in being undefined for the exact zero case.

Comment: $[(2/\pi)(1-\arctan(x-10))]$, where $[]$ is the "integer part" function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *unit step* is the function you're looking for.  In Boyce and DiPrima's Differential Equations text, they refer to this as $u_t(x)$.  It is defined as:
$$u_t(x) = \begin{cases}1 \quad \text{if }x \ge t\\
0 \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Then, you can write your function as:
$$f(x) = 1-u_{10}(x)$$

---

Another option is:

$$f(x) = 1 - \left\lfloor\frac{\lceil x-1\rceil}{10}\right\rfloor$$

Where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the floor function, and $\lceil\cdot\rceil$ is the ceiling function.

---

Another option is:
$$f(x) = [x \le 10]$$

Where $[\cdot]$ are [Iverson brackets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).